# How to use Freepik's seamless patterns in AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I want to use some seamless patterns from freepik to use as backgrounds but I'm absolutely lost as to how to use the files they provide. The artwork in the AI/EPS files don't actually tile properly as-is, so taking the asset and turning it into a pattern does not result in a seamless image.

I'm looking at this one specifically, but I've had this same issue with other freepik patterns. https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/flat-design-valentines-day-pattern-collection_11716525.htm

I'm honestly new to doing anything with AI and vectors in general so while I've looked at plenty of tutorials on how to make patterns in the program and I have gotten that to work, that doesn't help in this specific situation since the artwork is already made.

I can just take the artwork and manually copy/paste it over and over to match it up and turn it into a background, but I want to be able to actually use these as patterns later in Photoshop. What should I be doing with what the site is providing?

I feel like I may be missing something obvious so I apologize if that's the case, as well as my lack of usage of technical terms.

Comment: Look in the **Swatches Panel** there are actual *pattern swatches* there. [AI pattern help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/patterns.html)

Comment: I had tried this and thought it hadn't worked but now I see what was confusing me - the pattern swatches don't include the background color that the pattern on the image does, just the pattern objects. How do I get it to bring the bg color with it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the **Swatches Panel** (`Window > Swatches`) you'll see actual pattern swatches.

[image]

Simply draw a shape and fill it with one of these Pattern Swatches.

If you want to *also* have a background color....

Add a **new fill** via the **Appearance Panel** (`Window > Appearance`) and move it below the pattern fill.

[image]

Comment: Thank you VERY much! For some reason I was having trouble finding this explained in simple terms anywhere.